# How to figure out reason for last reset on MSP430?

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, reset, self-test

There are a number of possible causes for a microcontroller to reset *itself*, for example:

- brown-out or power-out
- watchdog timer
- reset initiated from software (to programmatically enter bootloader, etc)

I'm wondering if there is a way to figure out, when a microcontroller starts up, what was the reason for the last reset - perhaps using some kind of flags that survive reset.  In particular I'm on the MSP430F5xxx series.

The use case is to avoid a cycle where some part of the self-test routine (for example) causes a glitch on the power rail, and then the micro resets itself and runs the self test again, repeat (until it succeeds).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the reset source from checking the system reset interrupt vector (SYSRSTIV), there is a good description on the TI wiki ([Handling MSP430 System Reset Events](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Handling_MSP430_System_Reset_Events)).